# Manipulate variables in netcdf files and write them again

Tags: r, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have several netcdf files. each nc file has several variables. I am only interested in two variables "Soil_Moisture" and  "Soil_Moisture_Dqx".

I would like to filter "Soil_Moisture" based on "Soil_Moisture_Dqx". I want to replace values in "Soil_Moisture" by NA whenever corresponding "Soil_Moisture_Dqx"   pixels have values greater than 0.04.

:Here are the files to download:

1- I tried this loop but when I typed f[1] or f[2] I got something weird which means that my loop is incorrect.I am grateful to anyhelp to get my loop corrected.

```
 a<-list.files("C:\\3 nc files", "*.DBL", full.names = TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(a)){
f=open.ncdf(a[i])
A1 = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="Soil_Moisture",verbose=TRUE)
A1* -0.000030518509475997 ## scale factor
 A2 = get.var.ncdf(nc=f,varid="Soil_Moisture_Dqx",verbose=TRUE)
A2*-0.0000152592547379985## scale factor
A1[A2>0.04]=NA ## here is main calculation I need
 }
```

2- Can anybody tell me to write them again?

Comment: the scale factor looks ugly! how did you get this?

Comment: from the varible (A) metadata `[1] "var has BOTH add_offset ( 0 ) and scale_fact ( 3.05185094759971e-05 )"`

Comment: Once you update the A1 , you need to save your file again with NA values, isn'it?

Comment: yes that exactly what I need.update it according to the condition  `A1[A2>0.04]=NA`

Comment: I ask because I don't see in your code any save , like **put.var.ncdf**, and close(f)..

Answer (score 3):

Missing values are special values in netCDF files whose value is to be taken as indicating the data
is "missing". So you need to use `set.missval.ncdf` to set this values.

```
a<-list.files("C:\\3 nc files", "*.DBL", full.names = TRUE)

SM_NAME <- "Soil_Moisture"
SM_SDX_NAME <- "Soil_Moisture_Dqx"
library(ncdf)
lapply(a, function(filename){
  nc <- open.ncdf( filename,write=TRUE )
  SM <- get.var.ncdf(nc=nc,varid=SM_NAME)
  SM_dqx <- get.var.ncdf(nc=nc,varid=SM_SDX_NAME)
  SM[SM_dqx > 0.4] <- NA
  newMissVal <- 999.9
  set.missval.ncdf( nc, SM_NAME, newMissVal )
  put.var.ncdf( nc, SM_NAME, SM )
  close.ncdf(nc)
 })
```

**EDIT** add some check

It is intersting here to count how many points will tagged as missed.

Whithout applying the odd scale factor we have:

```
lapply(a, function(filename){
  nc <- open.ncdf( filename,write=TRUE )
  SM_dqx <- get.var.ncdf(nc=nc,varid=SM_SDX_NAME)
   table(SM_dqx > 0.4)
  })

[[1]]
[1] 810347     91

[[2]]
[1] 810286    152

[[3]]
[1] 810287    151

[[4]]
[1] 810355     83
```

Comment: Many Thanks. However,I got this error:`Error in put.var.ncdf(nc, SM_NAME, SM) :   NAs in foreign function call (arg 5)`

Comment: What a bout the scale factor,I do not see it in your answer!

Comment: `SM[SM_dqx > 0.4] <- NA`  can not be true unless the scale factor is  applied. Please add it. what about the error I have got?

Comment: This is really a mazing.It seems that the nc file takes into account the scale factor! no need to apply it.I am not sure.Please experts help us on this?

Comment: I am getting this error:`Error in put.var.ncdf(nc, SM_NAME, SM) : NAs in foreign function call (arg 5)`

Comment: @JonssonSali I will help you on this error. really I am not expert. I am not from the domain. I just I am little busy now , but I ll fix it.

Comment: @ agstudy if it is so difficult to put the file again in the netcdf file. we may jut write the resulted filtered variable outside.that is fine if you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished from the command line using CDO.

As I understand it both variables are contained in your input file (which I will call "datafile.nc", you will want to presumably do the following in a loop over the file lists), so first of all we will extract those two variables into two separate files:

```
cdo selvar,Soil_Moisture     datafile.nc soil_moisture.nc
cdo selvar,Soil_Moisture_Dqx datafile.nc dqx.nc
```

Now we will define a mask file that contains 1 when dqx<0.04 but contains NAN when dqx>=0.04

```
cdo setctomiss,0 -ltc,0.04 dqx.nc mask.nc
```

The ltc is "than than constant" (you may want instead lec for <= ), the setctomiss replaces all the zeros with NAN.

Now we multiply these together with CDO - NAN*C=NAN and 1*C=C, so this gives you a netcdf with your desired field:

```
cdo mul mask.c soil_moisture.nc masked_soil_moisture.nc
```

you can actually combine those last two lines together if you like, and avoid the I/O of writing the mask file:

```
cdo mul -setctomiss,0 -ltc,0.04 dqx.nc soil_moisture.nc masked_soil_moisture.nc
```

But it is easier to explain the steps separately :-)

You can put the whole thing in a loop over files easily in bash.